# Cython loop optimization | Python loop => Cython loop

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, optimization, cython

I need to speed up my Python loop, I decided to choose Cython for this. Unfortunately, I have no experience with Cython (and C lang). My attempt to create a fast loop in Cython failed.

Here is my Python function:

```
def backtest(data, min_distance):
    balance = 1000
    
    t1 = time()

    for shift_1 in range(1, 101):
        for shift_2 in range(1, 101):
            for shift_3 in range(1, 101):
                if shift_2 > shift_1 * min_distance and shift_3 > shift_2 * min_distance:

                    pnls_shift_1 = data[shift_1 / 10]
                    pnls_shift_2 = data[shift_2 / 10]
                    pnls_shift_3 = data[shift_3 / 10]

                    for pnl in pnls_shift_1:
                        balance *= (pnls_shift_1[pnl] / 100) * (33 / 100)

                        if pnl in pnls_shift_2:
                            balance *= (pnls_shift_2[pnl] / 100) * (33 / 100)

                            if pnl in pnls_shift_3:
                                balance *= (pnls_shift_3[pnl] / 100) * (33 / 100)

    print(time() - t1)
    return balance
```

Here's what I tried (Cython):

```
def backtest(dict data, float min_distance):
    cdef dict pnls_shift_1, pnls_shift_2, pnls_shift_3
    cdef int shift_1, shift_2, shift_3, pnl
    cdef int balance = 1000
    
    t1 = time()

    for shift_1 in range(1, 101):
        for shift_2 in range(1, 101):
            for shift_3 in range(1, 101):
                if shift_2 > shift_1 * min_distance and shift_3 > shift_2 * min_distance:
                    pnls_shift_1 = data[shift_1 / 10]
                    pnls_shift_2 = data[shift_2 / 10]
                    pnls_shift_3 = data[shift_3 / 10]

                    for pnl in pnls_shift_1:
                        balance *= (pnls_shift_1[pnl] / 100) * (33 / 100)

                        if pnl in pnls_shift_2:
                            balance *= (pnls_shift_2[pnl] / 100) * (33 / 100)

                            if pnl in pnls_shift_3:
                                balance *= (pnls_shift_3[pnl] / 100) * (33 / 100)

    print(time() - t1)
    return balance
```

As a result, the execution time in Cython turned out to be even longer than in native Python.
I think the problem is in the Python dictionary I'm using, but I'm not sure about that. I tried to switch from dict to list, but it was terrible and in the end nothing came of it.

My input dictionary looks like this:
`{0.1: {1: -2.5, 4: 3}, 0.2: {3: -1.5, 4: 1, 6: 0.24}, ... {10.0: {...}}}`

I would really appreciate it if someone would suggest optimization for this loop in Cython.

Comment: Just as an aside - floating point numbers as dictionary keys seems like an awful idea. You're one small rounding "error" away from your program breaking completely.

Comment: Also you've got two lines that assign to `t1` which makes it pretty unclear which times you're actually measuring

Comment: Forgot to remove the second t1. My dict always has a fixed number of keys (100), so there will be no error.

Comment: I think you missed the point about the floating point keys. The mathematical operations you use to get there affect the answer. Try `0.2+0.1 == 0.3` - on my PC it prints `False` because there's a tiny rounding error difference. Are you confident that this won't happen here?

Comment: Remove dictionaries ! I just speeded up my code by removing all dictionaries and using arrays only